How to get Gemini Flash to generate content with schema containing date/ datetime as a field?

I have a Pydantic class with datetime field which I would like to specify as the response schema in Gemini Flash. Error received is
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgument
400 * GenerateContentRequest.generation_config.response_schema.items.properties[date_of_birth].format: only 'enum' is supported for STRING type
I tried specifying as date and datetime types, but the same error in both cases.
